# How to create a draggable TabLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

My layout contains a TabLayout and a ViewPager, This views sits at the bottom.
I want to TabLayout to be draggable to the top of the page. Just the like the image below.[image]

The view is currently made with ConstraintLayout, how to do it?

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `CoordinatorLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` for achieving this output.

Refer the xml code taken:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
  ~ Copyright (C) 2015 The Android Open Source Project
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabContentStart="72dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tabs"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center|left|start"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_behavior="com.support.android.designlibdemo.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
        app:borderWidth="0dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Refer this complete thread for more ideas https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/1468510f046cb10c51ea

Comment: @Aslam did you check the complete thread? The example code I have shared here is for your reference!

Comment: actually this is good reference to achieve the task by OP, inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` OP can add the views he want which gets drag able with `NestedScrollView` in the bottom of  `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.Down voters Mind to reason please??